# How can I use a custom number format with velocity's NumberTool without generating an error?

Tags: java, velocity, number-formatting, currency-formatting

I want to use a custom currency format with Velocity's NumberTool but I'm getting an error with a valid format. Here's my code:

```
... $numberTool.format("¤###,###", ${amount}) ...
```

This generates an org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here is that Velocity is attempting parse the number format and getting confused. Here are two solutions:

- Use a variable to define your format and put it in the model before hand. Then just refer to it from your template. For example, in your Java file:

  ```
  model.put("DEFAULT_CURRENCY_FORMAT", "¤###,###");
  ```

  and in your template:

  ```
  $number.format(${DEFAULT_CURRENCY_FORMAT}, ${amount})
  ```
- Or you can simply use a different delimiter to specify your format. Even though the documentation for NumberTool.currency suggests that you use [double quotes](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/NumberTool.html#currency(java.lang.Object)) when you use NumberTool.format, you can use single quotes instead:

  ```
  $number.format('¤###,###', ${amount})
  ```

I prefer the first option, because you'll likely use the same format in multiple places and because it will allow you to use the ' character in your format should you need it.